# Code not working correctly when time input is 'xx:00'

Tags: php

I've got a form that allows the user to input a duration. If the duration is less than or equal to an hour, then 10 minutes are added to a field in my database, if the duration is more than an hour, 15 minutes are added.

I'm having an issue with the 'formula' code where it doesn't add 15 minutes if the input has 'no minutes'. So for example, if I input `02:20` or `01:55` or `01:05` it works perfectly and adds 15 minutes, but if the input is `02:00` or `03:00` or `04:00` and so on, it will only add 10 minutes. Below is the code.

```
$Duration = $_POST['Duration'];

$parsedDuration = explode(':', $Duration);

$hours = intval($parsedDuration[0]);
$mins  = intval($parsedDuration[1]);

if ($hours > 0 && $mins > 0) {
    echo "Added 15 maintenance minutes!";
    $MaintenanceDuration = strtotime('0:15:00');
} else {
    echo "Added 10 maintenance minutes!";
    $MaintenanceDuration = strtotime('0:10:00');
}

$MaintenanceDuration = strftime('%H:%M', $MaintenanceDuration);
echo $MaintenanceDuration;
```

If anyone could identify the issue here I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Remove the `&& $mins > 0`?

Comment: @Niet the Dark Absol - sorry this does not work.

Comment: `$hours > 0 && $mins != 0` ?

Comment: @Soywood - no result, sorry! Still produces 10 minutes with an input of 02:00

Comment: I which case you want to add 10 mins ? I don't get it

Comment: 02:00 would indicate 2 hours. If the input is more than one hour 15 minutes should be added.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the if condition

```
if ($hours > 0 && $mins > 0) to if ($hours > 0 && $mins >= 0)
```

Comment: Try this @sinesine.

Comment: Thank you but this isn't working either. I'm really not sure what's going on. Unless the fact that the format is xx:xx is something to do with it?

Comment: What inputs did you try it with?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure why it's not working for me then. On the form the HTML input is set to a time input, so it is in the format xx:xx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127400/discussion-between-sarath-kumar-and-sinesine).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (($hours * 60 + $mins) > 60) {
    echo "Added 15 maintenance minutes!";
    $MaintenanceDuration = strtotime('0:15:00');
}
else ...
```

If you want 01h00 to be in the 10min range, change `> 60` by `>= 60`